# htaccess RewriteCond how to not work in a folder and other files of that that

Tags: php, .htaccess

My htaccess file is.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ first.php
```

Now i want this rule not work in my admin folder
like my admin folder are `admin` 
so when my url is
 `admin/logout.php` 
then not work 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$`

or `admin/ajax/ajax.php` then it's same direct hit t
o `ajax.php` not redirect to
 `first.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple way would be to put a .htaccess file in your admin folder with the following statement

```
   RewriteEngine Off
```

This will disable all rewrites in your admin folder.

Answer (score 2):

Have your rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule !^admin/ first.php [L,NC]
```